# Regex for varying tags?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, bbcode

Not sure I worded the question correctly as I am new to Regex. I have a regex for a syntax I am working on for BBCode in sublime. This regex matches fine when used in this manner:

```
(\[color=red?(.*?)\])(.*?)(\[/color\])
```

> [color=red]Red Text[/color]

That works great for matching/grouping the code. But how would I go about capturing varying and extra tags in the match? For example if the bbcode would read:

> [center][size=6][color=red][b]Red Text[/b][/color][/size][/center]
>   or
>
> [center][size=6][color=red][i]Red Text[/i][/color][/size][/center]

That regex would capture the [b] and [i] tags within the 3rd group. How would I split the [b]/[i] tags to another group and include a 'varying' capture of [u][b][i] if it was used? The order wouldn't be consistent either. Not sure how this would be done.

Comment: There is a website http://rubular.com/ where you can test out your regex's easily.  I am far from a regex guru, so I've been using it since I found it.

Comment: Seems like what you really need is a parser since you're trying to deal with nesting

Comment: You mean this: http://www.regexr.com/38v9v

Comment: [All things are possible, but not expedient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).

Comment: I ended up using separate RegEx to identify certain scenarios in BBCode. (http://regexr.com/38va5) & (http://regexr.com/38vab) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This language is not regular, i.e. it can not be expressed using regular expressions.
You need a grammar and a parser to capture this language. See more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).